# Get native library dependencies via vcpkg in a C#/.NET project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, native, vcpkg

I have a C# project which needs to use (DllImport) the specific version of some C libraries developed (let's call them CommonLib) here at my company. CommonLib is available company-wide via a private vcpkg registry hosted as a Git repository. Our C++ projects use vcpkg in manifest mode thus is really straightforward to pass them around and get the right CommonLib version when building.
Obviously that isn't true for C#.

How can I automatically get the right version of native dependencies for a C# project when building, the right way?

I found some articles explaining how to wrap native libraries into nuget packages but my problem is to actually get them automatically from the registry during the build. I also found out that nuget packages can be exported from vcpkg but unfortunately this is not possible in manifest mode.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to figure this out?